# How to fix Unicode font error in JasperReport 6.0.20?

Tags: jasper-reports

How to fix Unicode font error in JasperReport 6.0.20? It is Vietnamese (UTF-8). I usually use Time News Roman, Arial font.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the fonts in Jaspersoft Studio under Preferences/Jaspersoft Studio/Fonts with the PDF embedding flag checked and Identity-H as PDF encoding.

[image: Jaspersoft Studio font]

If you want to generate reports in an application that uses the JasperReports library, you'll have to export the fonts as jars and include them in your application's classpath.

You should also check that the license under which you use the fonts allows you to embed them in generated documents.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DejaVu Sans` font.

[image]

See https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1012491/pdf-encoding-not-printing-characters-export

But I still want font Arial or Time News Roman font with Unicode UTF-8 display correctly. I still wait for more solution.